# Searching function for textbox and letting my function still run when there are none entries in for the textbox and listbox

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, listbox, multi-select

All I really need to know is how to make it where I can make selections in multiple multi-select listboxes, but leave any number of them blank and still have the macro/query work without having to put in an error message about it.

This also includes doing the same with the textboxes. The textboxes would function the same as the listboxes where they would search for anything in a data table to matches what I am looking for in the records and display what I am looking for in a table.

Here is my code

```vb
Private Sub Command62_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim District As String
Dim Circumstance As String
Dim Location As String
Dim Method As String
Dim Point As String
Dim Rank As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryMultiselect")

For Each varItem In Me!District.ItemsSelected
District = District & ",'" & Me!District.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(District) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Distrcit field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
District = Right(District, Len(District) - 1)

For Each varItem In Me!Circumstance.ItemsSelected
Circumstance = Circumstance & ",'" & Me!Circumstance.ItemData(varItem) & 
"'"
Next varItem

If Len(Circumstance) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Circumstance field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
Circumstance = Right(Circumstance, Len(Circumstance) - 1)

For Each varItem In Me!Location.ItemsSelected
Location = Location & ",'" & Me!Location.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(Location) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Location field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
Location = Right(Location, Len(Location) - 1)

For Each varItem In Me!Method.ItemsSelected
Method = Method & ",'" & Me!Method.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(Method) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Method field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
Method = Right(Method, Len(Method) - 1)

For Each varItem In Me!Point.ItemsSelected
Point = Point & ",'" & Me!Point.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(Point) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Point field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
Point = Right(Point, Len(Point) - 1)

For Each varItem In Me!Rank.ItemsSelected
Rank = Rank & ",'" & Me!Rank.ItemData(varItem) & "'"
Next varItem

If Len(Rank) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You did not select anything in the Rank field." _
, vbExclamation, "Nothing to find!"
Exit Sub
End If
Rank = Right(Rank, Len(Rank) - 1)

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblDataEntry " & _"WHERE tblDataEntry.District 
IN(" & District & ") AND tblDataEntry.Circumstance IN(" & Circumstance & 
") AND tblDataEntry.Location IN(" & Location & ") AND tblDataEntry.Method 
IN (" & Method & ") AND tblDataEntry.Point IN (" & Point & ") AND 
tblDataEntry.Rank IN(" & Rank & ");"

qdf.SQL = strSQL

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiselect"
Set db = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing

End Sub
```

I still need to add the textboxes, but I'm not sure where. (Please note that I'm still learning VBA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, since you are repeatedly performing the same operation for each form control (in this case, constructing a comma-delimited string from the selected items), you can abstract this operation away into a function, and pass such function each List Box function.

For example, you could define a function such as:

```vb
Function SelectedItems(objBox As ListBox) As String
    Dim strRtn As String, varItm
    For Each varItm In objBox.ItemsSelected
        strRtn = strRtn & ",'" & objBox.ItemData(varItm) & "'"
    Next varItm
    If strRtn <> vbNullString Then SelectedItems = Mid(strRtn, 2)
End Function
```

Which could then be evaluated with a List Box control argument, and would return either a null string (`""`) or a comma-delimited string of the selected items in the list box, e.g. something like:

```vb
?SelectedItems(Forms!Form1!List1)
'A','B'
```

Furthermore, since your form controls appear to be named consistently relative to the fields in your table, you could further condense your code to something along the following lines:

```vb
Private Sub Command62_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strArr As String
    Dim varItm

    For Each varItm In Array("District", "Circumstance", "Location", "Method", "Point", "Rank")
        strArr = SelectedItems(Me.Controls(varItm))
        If strArr <> vbNullString Then
            strSQL = strSQL & "t." & varItm & " in (" & strArr & ") and "
        End If
    Next varItm
    If strSQL <> vbNullString Then strSQL = "where " & Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)

    With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMultiselect")
        .SQL = "select * from tblDataEntry t " & strSQL
    End With
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiselect"
End Sub
```

Note that the above is entirely untested.

Here, the main `for each` loop iterates over an array of strings corresponding to the names of your form controls and the names of your table fields.

For each form control in this array, the function obtains a comma-delimited string of the selected items in the control, and concatenates this with the existing SQL code only if one or more items have been selected.

As such, if not items are selected, the field will not feature in the SQL `where` clause.

If any filter has been selected, the trailing five characters (`and`) are trimmed from the end of the SQL string, and the `where` keyword is concatenated to the start of the SQL string - this ensures that if no filter has been selected, the resulting SQL code will not include a `where` clause.

Finally, the SQL for the query definition is updated and the query is opened, per your original code.

---

Where textboxes are concerned, the task merely need to skip the call to `SelectedItems` and obtain the value of the textbox directly.

Here is an example incorporating both listboxes & textboxes:

```vb
Private Sub Command62_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strArr As String
    Dim varItm

    For Each varItm In Array("District", "Circumstance", "Location", "Method", "Point", "Rank")
        strArr = vbNullString
        Select Case Me.Controls(varItm).ControlType
            Case acListBox
                strArr = SelectedItems(Me.Controls(varItm))
            Case acTextBox
                If Not IsNull(Me.Controls(varItm).Value) Then
                    strArr = "'" & Me.Controls(varItm).Value & "'"
                End If
        End Select
        If strArr <> vbNullString Then
            strSQL = strSQL & "t." & varItm & " in (" & strArr & ") and "
        End If
    Next varItm
    If strSQL <> vbNullString Then strSQL = "where " & Left(strSQL, Len(strSQL) - 5)

    With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryMultiselect")
        .SQL = "select * from tblDataEntry t " & strSQL
    End With
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryMultiselect"
End Sub
```

I hope this helps, but please note that the above is untested and only theory.

Comment: I tested it out and it works the way that I have been trying to get it to work for quite some time! Thanks!

One more thing, is there a way for me to add in textboxes that could be used to search for other information. For example, if there is something I need about a description pertaining to text inform about an individual noted in the database and so on, how would I go about doing that? That has also been an issue that I have been running into and have not been able to implement well with out errors popping up.

Comment: Would I do essentially the same thing like with the multi-select listboxes or something different?

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the late reply, I will test this out tomorrow and I will see how it goes. Thanks again by the way!!

Comment: Tested it out, and I didn't have any success with it. Would I need to add in the "names" of the textboxes or is there something that I need to do to the textboxes for it to work properly?

Comment: @NMatsumiya *"Tested it out, and I didn't have any success with it."* That's not a lot of information to go on - did you receive any error messages? Have you added the names of your textboxes to the array? You'll need to take some time to understand the code I have provided.

Comment: Sorry about that. To be more specific I did not receive an error message, just what I had typed into one of my textboxes didn't come out with the results that I had initially thought. For example, in one of them the term "couple" is in there so I typed it in as such (without the quotation marks), but it did not exclude entries that did have the term "couple" in it.

Comment: The error that I get (after entering in the textboxes's names into the array) is that I get a report where it is blank and I get no results, does this mean that I would need to type out what is in there word for word or did I mess something up?

Comment: @NMatsumiya It's hard to advise without working with your database directly, but I would suggest inspecting the resulting SQL generated by my code (i.e. "design" the query "qryMultiselect") so that you can understand what is being output compared with what you require. I would also suggest taking some time to step through my code so that you can understand how the SQL code is being constructed.

Comment: Require: Results to be put into a table based on the information that is entered into the various textboxes, listboxes, and combo box (regardless if any of the boxes have any entries in them).

Generates: Essentially what I want, but the textbox search function doesn't work how I want it to, and requires that the entire entry is put in as opposed to using a word/phrase to search records and the date/time textbox does not search at all.

Comment: The code works in that I do not have to put entries in all the boxes to get results, but for the textboxes, it requires the entire entry in that corresponding textbox to search for it otherwise, it will display no results. Not sure why it does not work with the date/time one, though I'm assuming it is because the code has not been instructed to deal with that data. 

I assume that one of the possible solutions is to find a way where the code will allow me to have more freedom with what the textboxes can search for something along the lines of a ("*") or something like that correct?

Comment: Or at least something along the lines of (Like "*" & [forms]![tblDataEntry]![Description] & *) (Sorry for the long entry, the only allow to type in so much)

Comment: @NMatsumiya This is now straying far from the original question and becoming very broad. I have already provided code which answers your original question for both listboxes & textboxes. If you have additional questions on how to refine the code, I would suggest accepting this answer (and upvote if you wish) and posting a separate question so as not to muddy this thread.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion and I greatly appreciate the answers that I got towards the original question. Though I should have worded it differently, I will be sure to do that to try and get it all sorted out. 

I apologize for all the confusion.

Comment: @NMatsumiya No problem at all, I hope that my answer helped in some way towards your goal.

Comment: It did, but just a little stuck now that I have the other problem, but hopefully I will be able to figure it out.